# java a simple login system with user roles

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jframe, user-roles

im new to programming, java, mysql and everything. :) the point is, i've been trying to develop a normal form but with different user roles as admin and manager with a combo box in the login form, i have no idea how to code. btw the given user name and password in mysql works fine. i want to get it done with the combo box i have designed with user roles. i hope the people who have already have an experience regarding this can help me. i dont know whether my code is correct too, if it is not, please be kind to type the whole code and send. cheers.

```
{ package login;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestLogin","sa","root");
            String sql = "select * from log where username=? and password=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, username.getText());
            pst.setString(2, password.getText());

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
            userrole.addItem(rs.getString(1));//combo
            userrole.addItem(rs.getString(2));//combo
            panel.add(userrole);//combo
            this.getContentPane().add(panel);//combo
            this.setVisible(true);//combo
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password is Correct");
            Admin_Interface success = new Admin_Interface();
            success.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "UserID or Password is Incorrect, Try again");
            username.setText("");
            password.setText("");
            }
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }                                        

    private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        username.setText("");
        password.setText("");

    }                                        

    private void userroleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new login_form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is on valid java code; what class is this? Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are many ways you might implement this, you could have separate UI's for each role, you could break down the UI into separate components/functionality and build the UI dynamically based on the user role(s)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, your idea lead me for the solution years back. please post it as an answer. will accept! thanks!